# ユーザーコントロール上に図形を描画したい

Tags: c#, wpf

**やりたいこと**
WPFで追加のNugetパッケージなどを使用せずに、図形を描画したい。

**状況**
ImageSourceがBindされたUserControlを表示するMainWindowがあります。
このMainWindow、またはUserControl上に矩形選択の機能を持たせたいです。
コードビハインドでもMVVMでも構いませんので、やり方をご教授いただけると幸いです。
ご回答よろしくお願いいたします。

**ソース**
MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <local:Image />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Image.xaml

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="Image" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: この記事が参考になるかも。[Place a moveable reactangle on an WPF image control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17194110/9014308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

上記コメントのリンク先を参考にし、解決いたしました: [Place a moveable reactangle on an WPF image control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17194110)。
ありがとうございました。